# Undefined reference in single file?

Tags: c, undefined

So I understand that usually this error occurs when files aren't linked propely. The problem is I'm getting this from a single file, where things are being declared (no external files related to the function, this is all in one file):

For example:

```
inline SDL_Surface *ImgLoader(char *file,bool bCKey, int r , int g , int b , int alpha)
{
    SDL_Surface *pic;
    pic = IMG_Load(file); // From SDL_image.h , load the image to pic
    if(pic==NULL) fprintf(stderr,"Missing image %s : %s\n",file,IMG_GetError());
    if( bCKey ) {
        SDL_SetColorKey(pic,SDL_SRCCOLORKEY|SDL_RLEACCEL,SDL_MapRGB(pic->format,r,g,b));
        }
    if(alpha) SDL_SetAlpha(pic, SDL_SRCALPHA|SDL_RLEACCEL , 255 - alpha);
    pic = SDL_DisplayFormat(pic);
    return (pic);
}
```

Its usage:

```
anim[0] = ImgLoader("./anim/justice1.gif",1,255,255,255,230);
```

Why is this  occuring if the declaration of there?

EDIT: Sorry the error:

> undefined reference to `ImgLoader'

P.S. I know this is related to SDL, but I think this is more of a C related query than for games specifically.

Comment: Can we find a detail description of error :)

Comment: try declaring 1st param of ImgLoader() as `const char *file`

Comment: Please edit your question to actually include the error, unedited and complete. Or at least tell us what undefined references you have, we're not psycics you know.

Comment: Sorry about that! Completely skipped my mind for some reason. The error has been added. I'm using ImgLoader around 6 times and they all receive the error.

@suspectus, const char didn't change anything

Comment: Does your compilation command includes `-lsdl` or something equivalent, to link your program with the SDL library ?

Comment: Yes everything is there as required:

'-lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL'

Comment: Where is `ImgLoader` defined in relation to your other functions? If it's at the bottom of the file, then your other functions will have no knowledge of it. You could either define a prototype for it at the top of your file (`SDL_Surface ImgLoader(char *, bool, int, int, int, int);`), which should fix your problem but will negate the benefits of inlining; or just move the function to the top of the file.

Comment: The imgLoader function is declared _before_ it is being called. That's why I'm so confused as to why this occurs.

Comment: The keywords `inline` and `bool` indicates that this might be a C++ source file, and if so then you probably have to change the first argument to `const char *` since you call it with a constant string (a string literal). If would help even more if you post the _complete_ error message, as there are probably much more with more information.

Comment: I would guess "**An inline definition does not provide an external definition** for the function, and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit. An inline definition provides an alternative to an external definition, which a translator may use to implement any call to the function in the same translation unit. **It is unspecified whether a call to the function uses the inline definition or the external definition.**" that the compiler called the external definition, but the linker doesn't find it because there is none.